# Laravel Route Resource no funciona

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Tengo un problema, no se si hice algo mal.
Creé un nuevo proyecto y estoy probando las rutas.

Cree un controlador con recursos desde la consola '*MedicosController*'

Este es mi archivo. MedicosController.

```
class MedicosController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('welcome');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return "Hola";
}
```

Luego desde el archivo *Web.php* intento llamarlo como un recurso.

```
Route::resource('/Medicos',MedicosController::Class);
```

Desde la consola uso el comando *php artisan route:list*

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------ 
------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                   | Name            | Action                                         
| Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------ 
------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                     |                 | Closure                                        
| web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | Medicos               | Medicos.index   |App\Http\Controllers\MedicosController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | Medicos               | Medicos.store   |App\Http\Controllers\MedicosController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | Medicos/create        | Medicos.create  |App\Http\Controllers\MedicosController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | Medicos/{Medico}      | Medicos.show    |App\Http\Controllers\MedicosController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | Medicos/{Medico}      | Medicos.update  |App\Http\Controllers\MedicosController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | Medicos/{Medico}      | Medicos.destroy |App\Http\Controllers\MedicosController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | Medicos/{Medico}/edit | Medicos.edit    |App\Http\Controllers\MedicosController@edit    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user              |                 | Closure                                        
| api,auth:api |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------ 
------------------------+--------------+
```

El problema es que no me esta reconociendo la funcion *Create*.
Cuando en mi navegador intento llamarlo (Miproyecto/Medicos/create)

Me devuelve una pagina en blanco, cuando se supone que deberia devolverme ese 'Hola' o una vista, intento hacer que llame al Welcome (return view('welcome')) y tampoco me devuelve la vista. Sin embargo, si lo llamo de forma normal, sin usar el *Resource* si funciona.

Si lo llamo así

```
Route::get('Medicos/create',"MedicosController@create");
```

si llama a la funcion create. Es cuando uso el **Route::resource(...** que no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Comment: ¿Como lo estas llamando? Si el link lo pusiste en una etiqueta deberias de usar el helper route() de esta manera. <a href="{{ route('Medicos.create') }}">Link</a>

Comment: Estoy usando la 5.5

Comment: No, en realidad estoy llamandolo desde el archivo _web.php_, y no funciona.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que genera?

Comment: Tu problema este aqui: `Route::resource('/Medicos',MedicosController::Class);
` Esta sintaxis es valida a partir de Laravel 8. En la 5.5 debe ir así: `Route::resource('Medicos', 'MedicosController');` Link de la doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers
`

Comment: En realidad sin funciona, como dije el comando _artizan Route:list_ me devuelve la tabla con las direcciones, y funciona para la funcion _index_.
Pero cuando intento llamar al _create_ solo me devuelve una pagina en blanco, y debería devolverle el _'hola'_ pero no lo hace, solo me retorna una pagina en blanco. 
Es como que si encuentra la ruta _create_ pero no me deja retornar nada desde dentro de la función, los _return_ no funcionan.
Y se que encuentra la ruta, porque no me devuelve el mensaje de "pagina no encontrada"

Comment: @EdgarGc en realidad, por lo que vi, usar 'MedicosController::Class' tambien funciona en la version que estoy usando. 5.5.

Comment: @AldahirRuizValdez es **class** en minúscula, por favor siempre presta atención a esos detalles

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no se si esta sea una respuesta adecuada, pero a mi me funcionó.
Tenia el proyecto *MoonProject*, es este en el que no funcionaban las rutas, era un proyecto nuevo, apenas habia creado un controlador y estaba comprobando las rutas y no funcionaban, no se porque.

Probé crear un nuevo proyecto *Moon.Project*, copie el código tal y como lo tenia en el otro proyecto y aquí si funciona, es que no le cambie nada, el codigo es el mismo. No se que co*o sucedió.